# order placing emails not sending to admin

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-confirmation

I am using magento 2.3 for one of my clients. I am facing an issue that one of my customer placed an order. He is receiving the order detail mails. but i had not received the order placed mail.
how can i figure out this issue. I just check the SMTP email logs. In email logs we can only see the mails sent to the customers not to the admin(me).

thank you.